# Openwith.exe in process list multiple times unknown why

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, process

I know this is related to finding a program to use in win8+. I'm trying to migrate a server application from a 2008 R1 server to win2012 R2.

Is there a way I can figure out where the openwith.exe process is coming from or what it is associated with? I assume something is trying to open or run in the background, as I can't see anything and the openwith.exe comes up after a reboot. Sometimes I see many in there, right now 5 openwith.exes in my process list

My google-fu is failing me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out (in my case) this was related to trying to run a .vbs file via taskmanager, something we did in win2k3 and 2k8. Specifically Right Click Task Manager and show all running tasks, it showed OpenWith.exe for the Current Action (which made it stuck).

I had to modify how the file is executed on Win2012 R2 to get it to run properly.

Task Scheduled Action was:
program: "PATHTOFILE.vbs"

Now it is:
program: cscript
arguments: //nologo "PATHTOFILE.vbs"

Fixed 2 problems at the same time!